# update link through variables in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to build a script that will grab some text from a website and place it into an excel sheet, but I'm having trouble with using a variable in the URL, when using a variable my output is `http://@{variable=xyz}.com`, I'm trying to get the `xyz` only,
any help would be greatly appreciated

my code:

```
$ip = get-content c:\..
foreach ($ip in $ipadd){
$url = http://$ip/mywebsite.com
$html = invoke-webrequest -uri $url
$elements = $html.Allelements | where class -eq "class" | select -expandproperty innertext
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you are trying to use? It would be easier to help if we see what you could be doing wrong and give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using plain text and it worked just fine.
but id appreciate if anyone could tell me why I'm getting this `http://@{variable=xyz}.com` output from a csv file